# ffmpeg error: input packet contains no samples av_interleaved_write_frame()

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg to concat lots and lots of clips - that works perfectly fine in 99% of the cases. That said, sometimes I get this error:
[mov @ 0x7fcc94004000] fatal error, input packet contains no samples
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome

The output is still produced and looks fine – but I really would like to understand what throws this error. I'm pretty sure it's a problem with the audio – all clips have audio in the same format (PCM, little endian, 48 kHz, 16 bit), but one clip might have stereo, the other mono, and it only happens when mixing these. I have this all the time though and usually ffmpeg does not complain, so it must be something else on top. Any ideas?

Just for reference (I don't think the line is the problem, but…), this is how I call ffmpeg (from Python):
`subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-f', 'concat', '-safe', '0', '-i', path_concatlist, '-c:v', 'copy', '-c:a', 'copy', output])`

Comment: Yes I know, but as said: ffmpeg is quite robust with this and able to concat even mixed channels in 99% of cases. Converting all monoclips to stereo does make my error go away, but for the amount of clips I have (literally hundreds of thousands) this would take days and another harddrive, so I'd rather understand the exact issue instead of going down this road...

Comment: that makes a lot of sense – i did not notice this before, as the resulting clip is just a step in between, but i do certainly have half/double speed issues. thank you very much for this explanation and help! i'll go get this harddrive then…

Comment: ps. as it you did solve my problem, if you post your comment as answer, i'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## All inputs must have the same channel layout

Inputs must all be stereo, or all mono, but not mixed. Refer to this [list of properties that must match for proper concatenation](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/32597/how-to-create-compatible-avc-video-for-muxing-without-re-encode/32603#32603) with the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat).

## It's only working for you by chance

You just haven't tried a player that fails, stops between sections, plays half/double speed for the mismatched sections, and/or loses A/V sync. As inconvenient as it is, you have to make them all stereo or mono.

## Make them all the same

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -map 0 -c copy -c:a pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 48000 output.mov
```

Also see [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5784661/)

## Check channel layout with `ffprobe`

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams a -show_entries stream=channels -of csv=p=0 input.mov
```

It will either input nothing if there is no audio, or it will output the number of channels per audio stream. This is useful if scripting is involved.